# why d3 line is drawn only when i put data within in line function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to draw a line using data-join and a previous method I used before.

But when I go with data-join, it doesn't work out.

What did I miss?

line function is like below.

```
var lineFunc = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y })
```

1st method.

```
svg.append('path')
    .attr('d', lineFunc(geodata))
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('fill', 'none');
```

2nd method.

```
svg.selectAll('lines')
    .data(geodata)
    .join('path')
    .attr('d', lineFunc)
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
```

my data is

```
var geodata = [{ x: 0, y: 20 }, { x: 150, y: 150 }, { x: 300, y: 100 }, { x: 450, y: 20 }, { x: 600, y: 130 }]
```

I think both ways should work.
What shoudl I do if i want to draw the line using the 2nd method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line expect an array for each item. In your case, you only have one line so you just need to put `geodata` into an array like bellow:

```js
svg.selectAll('lines')
    .data([geodata]) // Like this
    .join('path')
    .attr('d', lineFunc)
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
```

Comment: This is the correct answer but doesn't provide any "why" context.  @BS100, the reason this works is because the line function expects an array of data.  When you do `.data(geodata)` it's going to call the line func for **every element** in the array.  By wrapping it in another array, it only gets called once on the inner array.

Comment: @Mark Thank you so much. I wasn't sure I understood the reason that it started working once it is wrapped within another array. It worked because the wrapping [geodata] turnned the array into an array which has only one index number. I got the logic now.